# How to understand my clion perf profiling report?

Tags: c++, profiling, clion, perf, ros2

I have an application and it is taking too long for some parts, now I profiled it and all the functions which I wrote only take a fraction of the total time around 20%. The most part 80% is spent in a call to libc-2.31.so__clone as can be seen in the profiling report. The thing is, I have no clue where and how I'm calling this function. Probably a lot of objects I'm creating are calling it. But how to know for sure? Is there a way to speed this part up? How can I speed it up if I don't even now where these calls happen? The "outer scope" is just all, which is not really helpful.
[image]

I checked out this guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/read-the-profiling-report.html#profiler-flame-chart and based on that I found following call list:
[image]

but that doesn't really help me out either. How can I properly figure out which part of my code is taking how long using the clion profiler?
Something like this in python:

```
import time
start = time.time()
do_stuff()
end = time.time()
print("Took:", end-now)
start = time.time()
create_objects()
end = time.time()
print("Took:", end-now)
```

Comment: DDSC is a communication layer, given how slow this is (relative to CPU speed) it's no wonder the code is spending most of time in here - it's probably waiting for packets to arrive (or to be sent).  A sampling profiler will count samples for code waiting to read a port, for example, even though the code at that time is potentially idle.